# Не могу задать окно для ввода текста через selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[image]
Вот на сайте, под который я пишу автореггер аккаунтов я на этапе ввода кода из смс, но почему-то никак не получается задать графу для ввода этого кода, вечно ошибка, что нет такого элемента

Сюда надо вводить код, но не поймут за что цепляться, пробовал через xpath по тексту, тоже ничего, люди помогите

[image]

Comment: какой xpath вы делали?

Answer (score -1):

выглядит так, что такой xpath будет работать `/input[@placeholder='Введите код из SMS']`

Comment: Не совсем, не работает

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Введите код из SMS']").send_keys('123456')

Comment: Вот так сделал, но в консоли ничего не происходит и не вводит ничего...